# Which version of controlsfx support with OpenFX and OpenJDK 11?

Tags: controlsfx, openjdk-11, openfx

I'm using `OpenFX 11`, `OpenJDK 11` and `controlsfx 8.40.15`  library

Getting   `Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.util.Iterator javafx.stage.Window.impl_getWindows()'` while execute following code.

```
    Notifications notifications = Notifications.create().title("Error").text("All fields are required.")
            .position(Pos.BOTTOM_CENTER);
    notifications.showConfirm(); //at this line geting error.
```

Maybe it is because of **incompatible** or **incomplete** library so is there have any solution?